# How to sort *packages* by Version

Tags: package

Is there a way to sort a list of packages in Package Menu (`*Packages*`) sorted by `Version`?  If you are using melpa, you see that melpa versions each package with `%Y%m%d.%d`.  I'd like to sort by the melpa version string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to enable sorting on all columns in the package menu's tabular list:

```
(add-hook 'package-menu-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq tabulated-list-format
                             (vconcat (mapcar (lambda (arg) (list (nth 0 arg) (nth 1 arg)
                                                            (or (nth 2 arg) t)))
                                       tabulated-list-format)))))
```

Comment: Thanks it works.  It'd be nice if it can take the numbers after the `.` as numbers.  But I think I can figure that out.

Comment: That reduces each element in the format to a 3-elements list. But the format accepts longer lists.